# Unable to set working directory using here package in R to another location

Tags: r, unix, directory, rstudio

I have a series of pieces of R code which have been designed to be run on other computers. That is, all code is relative to a root directory, which contains a Rstudio project file, .Rproj. There are no absolute file paths. This works fine when I actually open Rstudio, load the .Rproj file and then run the code.

However some of my code takes hours to run, and I need to set multiple scripts to run one after the other. This means creating a .sh file, and running the R script in turn from the command line. However non of my programs run successfully from the command line, as the root directory is no longer set to that of the .Rproj file. I have read about the here package can be used, which will automatically set the root directory to where ever a .here file is located. This is not the case for me.

The working directory it automatically uses is the home directory I have on the computational cluster I am using. The area where all my files, including the .Rproj and .here files is located in a different directory in which I have a lot more space allocated. Both are accessible from a common parent directory, so I assumed there here() function would be able to locate the directory I want to actually use to run my work. But this is not the case.

Effectively, I would like to set the root directory to a location which is not the default root directory on the system I am using. I have put a .here file there, but this is not located by there here() function, which I believe is its primary objective. Any ideas on how to proceed?

EDIT: I am working on a UNIX system. R version 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was similar, but not exactly the same as yours. Perhaps my solution will work for you. When I opened an RStudio project, I found that if I called "library(here)", the root directory is set where the .Rproj file is located and that "set_here" would not change that directory, despite the 'here' package documentation. Perhaps I was doing something wrong, but I decided to solve the problem with a simple R function that moves up the directory tree until it finds a ".here" file. It then loads the "here" package and that sets the root directory where I want it.

I use "touch .here" in a Terminal outside of R to set my root directory, and then call "init_here()" from my newly opened R project:

```
init_here <- function() {
  `%!in%` = Negate(`%in%`)
  files <- dir( all.files = T )
  while ( ".here" %!in% files & getwd()!="/" ) {
    setwd("..")
    files <- dir( all.files = T )
  }
  library(here)
}
```

Use Case -
In Unix:

```
cd( '~/myRoot' )
touch( '.here' )
```

In RStudio, when I open a project, the calls look like:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
< R information removed for clarity >

[Workspace loaded from ~/myRoot/myProject/.RData]

> getwd()
[1] "/Users/me/myRoot/myProject"
> init_here()
here() starts at /Users/me/myRoot
> here()
[1] "/Users/me/myRoot"
>
```

I can now put a ".here" file at the root of each of my RStudio projects and set the expected root directory independently for each project. If you want to get fancy, you could put the function in each project's .Rprofile so that it runs whenever the project is opened. All of my projects have the .Rproj file in the directory above my "R" directory, so my .Rprofile looks like:

```
source("./R/init_here.R")
init_here()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply adding a `cd /the/path/where/you/put/the/files` command in your shell script?

According to [this documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/here/versions/0.1), here() "uses a reasonable heuristics to find your project's files, based on the current working directory at the time when the package is loaded". The "cd" (**c**hange **d**irectory) command in a shell script changes the current working directory.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have to have the cd at the start of the shell script in order for it to properly locate the R scripts I want it to run, so it is already like this. The directory from which the programs are run (this is a child directory of the directory I would like to set to be the root in R), seems to have no bearing on what the working directory is automatically set to within R, or the heuristics from the here package.